# How to find square of n with a for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Can someone walk me through the following code:

```
function square(n) {
    let result = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (let j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            result += 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

//
example: 

console.log(square(5)) // 25
```

How does this for loop work in creating a square of an n number? I don't know where to start in approaching how this works.

Comment: Do you want it to be a nested loop?

Answer (score 2):

The square of a number can be visualized as the number of squares in a grid. 5x5, for example, is 5 wide by 5 tall:

[image]

You can think of the nested loop in your code

```
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        result += 1;
    }
}
```

emulating movement along the grid.

When `i` is 1, it's going along the first row. When `j` is 1, that corresponds to the first column. That corresponds to the first square. Next iteration corresponds to the first row, second column - etc, until `i <= n` is no longer fulfilled, at the end of the row. The next row then iterates `n` times, and so on.

You'll see that the number of total iterations (where `result += 1` runs) is equivalent to `n * n`, as the nested loop implements.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the inner(j) loop runs 5 times for every iteration of the outer(i) loop..

Basically,

```
for each i = 1, j runs 5 times
for i = 2, j runs 5 times //total 10 times
for i = 3, j runs 5 times //total 15 times
for i = 4, j runs 5 times //total 20 times
for i = 5, j runs 5 times //total 25 times
```

So the result gets incremented 25 times, and hence the answer is 25